# Regex pattern match for total count and specific order

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm currently writing regex patterns for driver license numbers for the 50 states of america. I've been able to them all with relative ease until Washington state came along. Here is what their license consists of (1-7 Alpha + Any combo. of Alpha, Numeric, or * for a total of 12 characters). Here is the regex I have come up with so far:

```
 new RegExp("^[a-z]{1,7}[a-z|0-9|*]{5,11}$");
```

This matches everything but the fact that it must also be 12 characters long. What would I need to add to also ensure that the total amount of characters entered = 12? I can do this with two separate patterns, but I would be much happier if I could do it with one since I've done every other state with just one.

Comment: Letters on my ID are capitalized, this only seems to match lowercase.

Comment: Yes, I lowercase the string before using the regex, a little less typing since I had to make a regex for each state.

Comment: You could also just use the `i` modifier to make the regexp case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that's typing the i modifier 50 times vs. doing .toLowerCase() once. I'm lazy....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead for that:

```
new RegExp("^(?=.{12}$)([a-z]{1,7}[a-z|0-9|*]{5,11})$");
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I had looked at lookaheads but wasn't understanding it, this makes much more sense.